# Make operation only when activity is running

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a loading activity which makes few requests to server and converts data. 
And layout of this activity is just simple logo image and `progressBar`.

All my operations were made in `onCreate()` and according to received request from server I start different activities:

```
if (request == 1) { start activity A} 
else { start activity B}
```

The problem is loading takes 2-3 sec and operations are made even before `onResume()`, before activity's view come to UI.

So its just blank activity which does some work.

**How can I ensure that those operations are made only after activity complete its creation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i clearly understand you you want to start activity 0 in which onCreate function is doing internet requests and after getting feedback from it you decide to call activity A or B. Is that correct? If yes you need to do network request in backgroud so your user interface thread doesnt freez. You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for example and on it's onPostExecute method decide to fire acitivty A or B

**EDIT**

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {
 protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
   //here  is background thread work calling net API request, hard working etc... but you can't touch UserInterface thread, since we are in background
  //here call your API and parse answear
  String ret = flag
  return flag;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {

 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  //here you are getting your flag from doInBackground as a result parameter
     // this is executed after doInBackground, fired automatically and run on User interface thread here you can for example modify layout so you can run activity A OR B 

 }
}
```

and if you have your logic in AsyncTask you can run it from onCreate for example it doesn't matter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    new YourAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

So you layot will be displayed and after executed your onPostExecute will be called

Comment: Yes, you've got it correctly. And is there a matter where I start AsyncTask? I mean, in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` etc?

Comment: And does `onPostExecute()` executes after activity was fully intialized and created?

Comment: this doesn't work. I've made all operation in `doInBackground()` and trying to start new activity from `onPostExecute()`.  And it seems like it doesnt reach `onPostExecute` at all

Comment: Show us what you  did. Probably small mistake smowhere.

Comment: seems like I found the problem. I just needed to add `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before starting new activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to move that server call off the main ui thread.  Use an IntentService or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from this question, you must be using AsyncTask or Service to connect to server. You put the main thread in while loop and AsyncTask or Service is doing the required operation for you. After operation is complete, it will break out of while loop and then use if/else loop and decide which activity to start next.

Something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       boolean isDone = false;
       // initialization code here

       // start AsyncTask
        BackgroundThread.execute(params);
        while(!isDone)
        {
           Thread.sleep(1000);   // 1 sec
        }
}
doInBackground()
{

         // your code
         isDone = true;
}
```

onPostExecute() is executed on main thread, not on background thread.